# Redirect in javascript not working on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, redirect

I'm trying to force a redirect in JavaScript to another website of mine, this works but not on iOS devices.

I have tried numerous ways to get this to work on iOS devices and all fail:

```
location.href = redirectUrl;
window.location.href = redirectUrl;
setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = redirectUrl;},250);
window.location.replace = redirectUrl;
windowLocation(redirectUrl);
window.location.assign(redirectUrl);
window.location = redirectUrl;
```

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: When do you need to change the website url ? When the user click on a button or just when the user opens the website?

Comment: When the user click on a submit button and after submit ajax success redirect.

Comment: @DivyamGhedia, did you get this working? What was the solution?